# orQueryWithSubqueries Counting All Objects

Tags: ios, swift, parse-server

When trying to use a multitude of queries I'm getting all the results, its not actually filtering any data whatsoever. I have tried multiple ways to perform this and some reason I cannot get it to only show what I'm looking for.

```
func getOpenWorkOrders() {
    let query1 = WorkOrders.query()!
    query1.whereKey("status", equalTo: "New")

    let query2 = WorkOrders.query()!
    query2.whereKey("status", equalTo: "In Progress")

    let query3 = WorkOrders.query()!
    query3.whereKey("status", equalTo: "On Hold")

    let query4 = WorkOrders.query()!
    query4.whereKey("status", equalTo: "Assigned")

    let query5 = WorkOrders.query()!
    query4.whereKey("status", equalTo: "Ready To Bill")

    let queries = PFQuery.orQueryWithSubqueries([query1, query2, query3, query4, query5])
    queries.countObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (number : Int32, error : NSError?) in
        if error == nil {
            self.openWorkOrdersNumber.text = String(number)
        }
    }
}
```

is there something I am missing here?

This is the same way I'm doing it in the rest of my app

Comment: Your question is unclear. What results  are you getting?  What results  are you expecting?

Comment: I am getting results for the entire class, not just what I made the queries filter. I am expecting the filtered data. But i het 509, the total number of them in the database, instead of the correct number.

Comment: Perhaps use `containedIn` - http://blog.parse.com/announcements/new-tricks-with-queries/

Comment: That worked, thank you @Paulw11